# what is the command line to install xenial?

Tags: 16.04, crouton

I can install trusty using `sudo sh ~/Downloads/crouton -r trusty -t xfce`, and need to update to xenial. I'm using Crouton with Crosh on Chromebook.

I'm new at Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading Ubuntu Desktops to 16.04 (Recommended)
You can easily upgrade over the network with the following procedure.

1. Run the `update-manager` application from the `Unity Dash` or a `command line`
2. In Update Manager, click the `Settings...` button, and enter your password to start the Software Sources application.
3. Select the sub menu Updates from the Software Sources application.
4. Confirm the "Notify me of a new Ubuntu version:" option is set to "For any new version", and change it if otherwise.
5. Close the Software Sources application and return to Update Manager.
6. In Update Manager, click the Check button to `check` for new updates.
7. If there are any updates to install, use the Install Updates button to install them, and press Check again after that is complete.
8. A message will appear informing you of the availability of the new release.
9. `Click Upgrade`.
10. Follow the on-screen instructions.

For servers:

1. Install update-manager-core if it is not already installed:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
   ```
2. Launch the upgrade tool:

   ```
   do-release-upgrade
   ```
3. Follow the on-screen instructions.

Source:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/XenialUpgrades